# Is there an easy way to search for all LOV's in a given Application/Project?

Tags: java, project, jdeveloper

I am working on a fairly large project.  I need to find all LOV's in a single application and modify them.  The application has about 4 projects.  There might be about 300 LOV's.  Is there an easy way to search for these?  Could I regex this?  Is there a way to get a data model diagram of all LOV's.

Any response is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A LOV is defined by one or more tags depending on the kind of LOV (select one choice, combobox, input select one choice,...).
You can use any tool that can look for text inside files to search for specific tags.

As you did not tell us the framework you use I give you a sample for the tag  ADF selectOneChoice uses:

```
af:selectOneChoice
```

So you can search the projects folders for all files containing this text. As you tagged the question with JDeveloper, you can use JDevs Find->'Find in Files...' menu option. In the dialog you get, you enter the right data where to look (scope) and what to look for(Search Text). There are more options you can use to get faster and better results. Click on the '?' button to get more help on how to use this feature.